# Writing List Comprehensions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Python and trying to improve my understanding of list comprehensions.

I would like to convert the for loop below into a list comprehension. My effort fails with an error message that I am unable to decipher:
`IndexError: ('index 17 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3', 'occurred at index 0')`

Code:

```
# 1: Original Code With For Loop (Working)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame([2,20], index=['b','a'])
B = pd.DataFrame([3,4,5], index=['a','b','c'])
C= A-B
print(C)

for x in range(3):
    if ~np.isnan(C.iloc[x][0]):
        C.iloc[x] = C.iloc[x][0]
    else:
        C.iloc[x] = B.iloc[x][0]
print(C)


# 2: New Code Incorporating List Comprehension (Not Working)
A = pd.DataFrame([2,20], index=['b','a'])
B = pd.DataFrame([3,4,5], index=['a','b','c'])
C= A-B
print(C)

C.apply(lambda x: C.iloc[x][0] if ~np.isnan(C.iloc[x][0]) else B.iloc[x][0])
```

Comment: Where is the failing attempt?  I don't see a list comprehension attempt in this code.  It's hard to help when we can't reproduce the problem.  The bottom line of your code is the closest, but that's a generator in a function call, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I did say I was still fairly new to Python. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you want?

```
In [177]: A.sub(B).fillna(B)
Out[177]:
      0
a  17.0
b  -2.0
c   5.0
```

or this:

```
In [178]: A.sub(B, fill_value=0)
Out[178]:
      0
a  17.0
b  -2.0
c  -5.0
```

yet another Pandas solution:

```
In [193]: C
Out[193]:
      0
a  17.0
b  -2.0
c   NaN

In [194]: C.where(C.notnull(), B)
Out[194]:
      0
a  17.0
b  -2.0
c   5.0
```

Comment: That certainly works and is very elegant. Thank you. It didn't help me with attempt to understand list comprehensions which I see was a result of my poorly worded question!

Comment: @PeteB, i intentionally didn't answer with list comprehension solution, because we should almost always try to avoid using loops when working with Pandas, as it almost always gives us a chance to use much faster and more efficient vectorized method

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in range(3):
    if ~np.isnan(C.iloc[x][0]):
        C.iloc[x] = C.iloc[x][0]
    else:
        C.iloc[x] = B.iloc[x][0]
```

The list comprehension would be

```
[C.iloc[x][0] if ~np.isnan(C.iloc[x][0]) else B.iloc[x][0]
    for x in range(3) ]
```

Then you need to assign the resulting list to the appropriate variable.  I can't do this, since you didn't include enough of your code to test the result in your context.

As the previous answer shows, however, this is probably not the best way to achieve this particular result.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. What extra information do you need to assign the resulting list to a variable? I was hoping to update C when it is nan with the value of B.

Comment: I don't know the structure of C.iloc; if this is a PANDAS structure, tehn list comprehension is probably not the construct to use.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused with your response. C is defined in the code above as A-B. A, B and C are panda DataFrames. Also, why do you suggest list comprehensions are not a viable construct for use with pandas?

Comment: It's a viable construct; I just don't know that a direct list assignment matches the construct.